# how to use preparestatement without implementing a method in my connection class

Tags: java, jdbc, jtable, prepared-statement, resultset

i am trying to fill my jtable in java with my data from the database.
I have a connection class and i can connect to the server but when i try to use the prepareStatement the eclipse tells me to add cast or to create a prepareStatement method in my connection class... below my code

connection class

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DBConnection {

    public static Connection con;

    public DBConnection() throws Exception {

            try{
        String intraUrl = "jdbc:mysql://blabla:3306/"; //HS-URL

        String db = "";     //Database name
        String user = "";   //user of this db
        String pw = "";     //Password of user

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(intraUrl + db, user, pw);
                con.setAutoCommit(false);

            } catch(Exception e){new Exception("Connection failerd!");}
    }

}
```

class where i want to fill the jtable

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.*;

import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class FlugzeugTypAnlegen extends JFrame {

    static DBConnection con;
    private JTable table;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FlugzeugTypAnlegen frame = new FlugzeugTypAnlegen();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // Objekt der DBConnection Klasse um zur Datenbank zu verbinden
        try {
            new DBConnection();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sie sind mit der HolgAIR Zentrale Verbunden!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public FlugzeugTypAnlegen() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 948, 647);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

JButton button = new JButton("Tabelle Laden");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try{
                    String query = "select IDFlugzeugtyp as ID, Name, Typ, Reichweite, FirstClassMax as Firstclass, BusinessClassMax as Businessclass, EconomyClassMax as Economyclass from Flugzeugtyp";
                    PreparedStatement sta = DBConnection.con.prepareStatement(query)
                    ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery();

                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();    
            }
            }});
```

thx for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the missing semicolon, and in the absence of an actual error message, I don't see what your problem is.

But you don't want to do any of this. A static `Connection` won't last for the life of your executable, and unless your application is completely single-threaded it will fail anyway. You want to get a new `Connection` as neeed and close it when finished. You should change your `DBConnection` class to be final and have a *static* method that returns a *new* `Connection.`